# Group by if condition

Tags: ms-access

I have a total query where I group by an id, and take a date1 field from the first and a date2 from the last row in each group. What I would like to do is to group only if there is no difference between to the two dates.

Say for example that I have this table:

```
id     date1       date2 
1      1-1-2012    5-5-2012
1      5-5-2012    27-6-2012
2      26-4-2012   23-8-2012
2      22-5-2012   5-6-2012
```

I would like to make this selection:

```
id     date1       date2 
1      1-1-2012    27-6-2012
2      26-4-2012   23-8-2012
2      22-9-2012   5-12-2012
```

I have a very large table, so the query must be relatively efficient. Any suggestions on how this could be done?

Comment: Please explain the logic which results in that second row for id=2 in your desired output.

Comment: I think the third line was a mistake from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't give you the answer, but it might help someone get over the finish line.  I just haven't had my coffee yet...  :o)

```
SELECT T1.ID, Min(T1.Date1) as Dt1A, Max(T1.Date2) as Dt2A, Max(T2.Dt1) as Dt1B, Max(T2.Dt2) as Dt2B, IIF(Max(T2.Dt1) = Max(T2.Dt2), "True", "False") as Status
FROM tblDateStuff as T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, Max(Date1) as Dt1, Min(Date2) as Dt2
    FROM tblDateStuff
    GROUP BY ID
    ORDER BY ID ASC) as T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID
ORDER BY T1.ID ASC
```

You may need to wrap this whole block of code into a bigger block and do something with that.  It seems like you only want to group if Status = "True", but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I didn't know I could use min(), max(), fist() and last() as functions in at groupe by selection. I'll try using them to build somthing.